# Where can I find documentation for pd.Timestamp.value

Tags: pandas

I checked these two sources:

- https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.value.html#pandas.Timestamp.value
- https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/main/pandas/_libs/tslibs/timestamps.pyx

but still unclear with what it does. I'm not very familiar with cython code.

Just based on poking around, it seems to return the number of nanoseconds since epoch.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> ts = pd.Timestamp("1970-01-01")
>>> ts.value
0
>>> ts = pd.Timestamp("1970-01-01 00:00:00.123")
>>> ts.value                                    
123000000
>>> ts = pd.Timestamp("1969-12-31 23:59:59")    
>>> ts.value
-1000000000
```

I wonder if it's documented somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not explicitly documented, but yes - `value` is the count of [`resolution`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.resolution.html)s (defined as `Timedelta('0 days 00:00:00.000000001')` = `1 ns`) since epoch:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> ts = pd.Timestamp("1970-01-01 00:00:00.123")
>>> ts.resolution * ts.value
Timedelta('0 days 00:00:00.123000')
```

See also:

[Epoch timestamps](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/timeseries.html#epoch-timestamps):

> The default unit is nanoseconds, since that is how Timestamp objects
> are stored internally.

[Timestamp limitations](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/timeseries.html#timestamp-limitations):

> Since pandas represents timestamps in nanosecond resolution, ...